# can you use excel macros to place html codes around selected text

Tags: excel, vba

I am using Excel to prepare a database for eventual use on a website. What I want to do is to rapidly mark particular words in cells used as text fields as to be italicised - i.e add html codes before and after them. Ideally I would like to be able to select a piece of the text then run a macro to put these codes at either end of the selection.

example text:
The species is similar to Calcidiscus protoannulus but strongly elliptical

This text is in a cell and I want to be able to rapidly place the html codes around the name Calcidicus protannulus

Comment: Are the items you want to format consistent or do they vary?  So if Calcidiscus Protoannulus is a variable how many other values are there?

Comment: What prefix and suffix codes do you want to use??

Comment: unfortunately, no, there are numerous differentitems which need formatting. NB Apologies for not replying sooner, email notifications to me did not work for some reason. The odes can be either <i> or <em>

Comment: I did not find a way to do this in excel and instead wrote an applescript to do the same thing

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example for "happy"

```
Sub qwerty()
    Cells.Replace "happy", "<i>happy</i>"
End Sub
```